# black screen instead of login screen but can hear sounds

Tags: boot

I have problem with booting my ubuntu on laptop.

After boot I have only black screen. I can hear sounds by pressing volume buttons, I can enable cli mode, but Im not able to do anything else. Only solution for that is closing my laptop and opening it again. It acts exactly like on this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cLzAR2ed4EY

I already tried to use quiet splash, nomodeset, grub_gfxmode=... etc.

What can I do to fix that?

Im using Lenovo Yoga 11e 3rd gen with Intel Celeron N3150 and integrated graphic card. I have same problem on ubuntu 19.04, 18.04.2. Also tried Kali and Mint but with same result.

Comment: do you know what graphic chip is being used?

Comment: lshw shows smth like this: VGA compatible controller Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register, vendor Intel Corporation version 21 width 64 bits clock 33 MHz

Comment: Issue this command and post the output sudo lspci|grep VGA

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 21)